# I'm unable to display a form dynamically

Tags: php

When I try to use the `<form> </form>` tag dynamically, it is not working.

Sample code:

```
<?php
   $i=1;
   while($i<4)
   {
       <form name="form'.$i.'" action="" method="post">
           <input type="submit" name="a'.$i.'" />
       </form>
       $i++;
   }
?>
```

The code runs, but the form tag doesn't work for the first button. It works from the second button. But I need this for the first button also.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The code the way you posted it - will not work at all! please post the *real* code otherwise people here won't be able to help you debug the error.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "does not work for the first button", but if I were you, I would remove the single quote from inside the double quote. so your form name would be form.$i instead of form.'$i' as it is cleaner.

Comment: This is the code. If this works fine then all other will work. But this simple one is not working.

Comment: @WahabMirjan i have tested the code given by you. But it shows the same problem. The form tag is not there for the first button and appears to come for the second and third button. So the first button is not submitting any value.

Comment: Please provide working code if you wish help

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?php
   $i=1;
   while($i<4)
   {  
       echo '<form name="form'.$i.'" action="" method="post">
       <input type="submit" name="a'.$i.'" >   </form>';
       $i++;
   }
?>
```

Comment: i have done the echo but still the same problem. Form tag is not working for the first button.

Comment: Not working. You can check it.

Comment: @ShubharajPaul checked and working fine

Comment: @ShubharajPaul check http://www.brightmeup.info/test.php same code i written ..

Comment: @ShubharajPaul: Define "not working" There's no PHP error code that says "Not working".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<4)
{
?>

<form name="form_<?php echo $i; ?>" action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="a_<?php echo $i; ?>"/>
</form>
<?php
$i++;
echo "yes";
}
?>
```

Comment: same problem. Doesnt work for the first button

Comment: what are you doing on buttons, please update the code, plase write complete code

Answer (score 0):

You are combining PHP with HTML together. There is more than one approach, but I personally like the followiong

```
<?php
    $i=1;
    while($i<4)
    {
?>

        <form name="form<?php echo $i; ?>" action="" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="a<?php echo $i; ?>" />
        </form>

<?php
    $i++;
    }
?>
```

The reason I like the above approache is I do not like to use echo statements to write HTML, this is clearer, at least to me.

Comment: how the $i in `form'.$i.'"` and ` name="a'.$i.'"` will work ? i think you havent  read completely

Comment: I just updated the code, I did not see the $i inside your form.

Comment: it is working from the second button then. Why is it not showing problem in any other button except the first?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain more?